Receiving 403 response due to missing User-Agent
I am working with some WordPress sites that possess API calls to complete various tasks, such as saving data or sending transactional messages.
I have been advised that one of our clients is updating their endpoint, so we have to update all of our API calls with the updated URL.
After updating the URL endpoints, I started getting a 403 response.
I was only getting 200 responses prior to this update.
Postman is giving me 200 responses with the updated URL.
According the our client, it seems that our calls are missing the user-agent, that which was not needed before but apparently is needed now as it is triggering the Web Application Firewall of the client.
Postman seemingly automatically includes the user-agent which is why it works there.
The client provided an example of how the user-agent should look:
"User-Agent": "YourAppName/1.0"

I was able to find the User-Agent by going to the Chrome inspector, clicking network, clicking a request, then scrolling down the header.
It reads something like this:
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel somestuff) AppleWebKit/somenumbers (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/morenumbers Safari/lastnumbers

It seems obvious but please let me know if this is the correct location.
Using the above User-Agent, this was my attempt to include it in my already functional API call:
<?php
// transactional send
$userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel somestuff) AppleWebKit/somenumbers (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/morenumbers Safari/lastnumbers';

$url = "https://updated.api.net/" . $account . "/api/transactional/send";
$xun = "USERNAME: " . USERNAME;
$xpw = "PASSWORD: " . PASSWORD;
$xac = "ACCOUNT_CODE: " . ACCOUNT_CODE;
$xag = "USER-AGENT": " . $userAgent;
$content = '{
 "message_id": 'someID',
 "campaign_id": 'anotherID',
 "recipients": ["'myemail@yahoo.com'"],
 "sending_connection_id": 'sendID'
}';

$curl    = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
     "Content-type: application/json",
    $xun,
    $xpw,
    $xac,
    $xag
) );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content );
$json_response = curl_exec( $curl );
$status        = curl_getinfo( $curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );

if ( $status != 200 && $status != 201 ) {
    error_log( "Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, response $json_response, 
    curl_error " . curl_error( $curl ) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno( $curl ) );
}

echo "<script>alert('$status');</script>";

curl_close( $curl );

$response = json_decode( $json_response, true );
?>

Using the above, I am able to print an alert window to the screen.  And this is where I am getting the 403 response.
Keep in mind that when I switch the URL back to the original URL, I get my 200 response and I can see the message come to my email.
What did I do wrong and how can I fix it?

There's obviously a typo in your code. Even the syntax highlighting on stack overflow is off after the user-agent line. Check your colon

$xag = "USER-AGENT": " . $userAgent;  that's one too many quote characters

Sounds like they broke their api without any concern for their clients.
The User-Agent request header is part of the RFC9110 HTTP Semantics Specification

10.1.5. User-Agent The "User-Agent" header field contains information about the user agent originating the request, which is often used by
servers to help identify the scope of reported interoperability
problems, to work around or tailor responses to avoid particular user
agent limitations, and for analytics regarding browser or operating
system use. A user agent SHOULD send a User-Agent header field in each
request unless specifically configured not to do so.
User-Agent = product *( RWS ( product / comment ) ) The User-Agent
field value consists of one or more product identifiers, each followed
by zero or more comments (Section 5.6.5), which together identify the
user agent software and its significant subproducts. By convention,
the product identifiers are listed in decreasing order of their
significance for identifying the user agent software. Each product
identifier consists of a name and optional version.
product         = token ["/" product-version]    product-version =
token A sender SHOULD limit generated product identifiers to what is
necessary to identify the product; a sender MUST NOT generate
advertising or other nonessential information within the product
identifier. A sender SHOULD NOT generate information in
product-version that is not a version identifier (i.e., successive
versions of the same product name ought to differ only in the
product-version portion of the product identifier).
Example:
User-Agent: CERN-LineMode/2.15 libwww/2.17b3 A user agent SHOULD NOT
generate a User-Agent header field containing needlessly fine-grained
detail and SHOULD limit the addition of subproducts by third parties.
Overly long and detailed User-Agent field values increase request
latency and the risk of a user being identified against their wishes
("fingerprinting").
Likewise, implementations are encouraged not to use the product tokens
of other implementations in order to declare compatibility with them,
as this circumvents the purpose of the field. If a user agent
masquerades as a different user agent, recipients can assume that the
user intentionally desires to see responses tailored for that
identified user agent, even if they might not work as well for the
actual user agent being used.


the user agent is the machine/os/application that is being used to make the api call.. reusing the mozilla browser user agent string is not recommended as it doesn't accurately depict the client making the call.

So they said that they wanted to use the new URL in an attempt to increase security.  Are you saying that this is something on their side that they need to fix?

my comment was just pointing out they made a breaking change without consideration of their existing clients.  If it's a security fix, they probably don't care about breaking clients and forcing them to update.  This is something you need to fix from your side if they are requiring this header
